# Dynamic thumbnail from image in another div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to clone a thumbnail image from an image in another div?

I have a bunch of divs like this:

```html
<div id="itemXX" class"product">

  <div class="image">
    <figure>
      <img src="imageXX.jpg">
      <figcaption>editable</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    <p>editable</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

They get swapped when clicking on a thumbnail (inside a list item) which also has to point to "imageXX.jpg" …I want the thumbnail to update automatically when changing the .product div img.

jQuery-dependent ok.

edit: would it be possible to do this with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible you can use clone() and appendTo functions in jQuery.

your HTML was:

```
<div id="itemXX" class"product">

  <div class="image">
    <figure>
      <img src="imageXX.jpg">
      <figcaption>editable</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    <p>editable</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

add this jQuery this will clone whatever is in div class image to the div with class description. feel free to manipulate the code and have fun.

```
$(".description").click(function(){
    $(".image").clone().appendTo(".description");
    });
```

thanks.

Comment: Thanks but I want the image duplicate to show on load or on refresh and not after clicking anything. Also the cloned image goes on a ul li elsewhere on the page where there'll be many of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a codepen with a solution:

```js
var img = jQuery("#image01").children("img").clone(); jQuery("#thumb01").append(img);
```

This does what I want. Only issue is I'm adding one of this functions per image/thumbnail (which can go up to 15) …if there's a way to do it via class or array or something I'd love to hear it, otherwise I can live with this.